# undefined method `transform_keys' loading Sidekiq web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

After updating gems, it does not load the sidekiq website giving the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `transform_keys' for <ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x00005568df2a8710>):
```

The gems that were updated were:

```
selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
rack-protection 2.0.8.1
mime-types 3.3.1
 mini_magick 4.10.1
image_processing 1.10.3
groupdate 4.3.0
friendly_id 5.3.0
faraday 0.17.3
http 4.3.0
public_suffix 4.0.3
rack 2.1.1
crass 1.0.6
i18n 1.7.1
minitest 5.14.0
```

ruby version: ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]

[Full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrrB3.jpg)

Comment: What version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails do you use?

Comment: @spickermann is asking because [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) was added to the Ruby core fairly recently, in v2.5.

Comment: @spickermann ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @rhugo Can you please post the full error message including the stack trace and the code which triggers the exception (see stack trace to identify where the error occurs in your application).

Comment: @spickermann I added an image with the log, it doesn't let me include so much code in the message

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba solved using rack 2.0.8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update: Rack 2.1.2 has been released and it solves this error

Now the solution is making sure you use 2.1.2 or higher.

```
bundle update rack
```

might do the trick for you depending on the rest of your Gemfile.

---

### Old answer

Two options in order to solve this.

- Install a previous working release (recommended). This will install the latest release on 2.0.X branch:

```
gem 'rack', '~> 2.0.0'
```

- Install the fixed version from git repository itself

```
gem 'rack', github: 'rack/rack', ref: 'f690bb71425aa31d7b9b3113829af773950d8ab5'
```

In both cases, you should remove/replace this with the proper fixed release once this happens. Keep track of https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1428

Answer (score 36):

It seems to be an issue with Rack 2.1.1. It works ok with 2.0.8.

Comment: It has been fixed in Rack 2.1.2, which was just released a couple hours ago.

Comment: I've updated to Rack 2.1.2 but Sidekiq renders blank pages. Downgrading to 2.0.8 makets it to work again. More issues here: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1531

Answer (score 21):

it's a rack issue and fixed by this PR: https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1428

Answer (score 5):

For me, I solved this problem by adding this line to `Gemfile`

```rb
gem 'rack', '2.0.7'
```

If you have `Gemfile.lock` in local, you can delete it and then run `bundle install`.

If you are using Capistrano, you needn't run `bundle install` manually, and `Gemfile.lock` often doesn't exists in your repository.